# sensor AMG8833 with raspberry pi5

Tags: adafruit

I tried to follow several guides to get the AMG8833 working with the Raspberry Pi 5. The latest one I tried was this guide:https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-amg8833-8x8-thermal-camera-sensor.pdf , but I didn't get any results.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is your question?... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Answer (score 0):

Please check your power supply. Also, check if you have downloaded and installed the libraries properly.